# The network is terribly slow between Hololens2 and PC using MR-WebRTC on the WAN

Tags: webrtc, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I want to set up a video chat between Hololens and PC using MR-WebRTC. I have a coTurn server configured to accept Stun/Turns. Everything is fine when I test on the LAN, but terrible on the WAN. The video captured by Hololens cards terribly in the PC when I test on the WAN. Transmitting a 331KB picture using MR-WebRTC on the WAN needs about 13s. I wonder how to figure out that if I have a successful NAT traversal and if NAT traversal is failed, MR-WebRTC would transmit data using a relay server or any other ways.

**Hololens LocalVideo Webcam Source:**
Capture format:manual
Width:1280
Height:720
Framerate:30

**Environment:**
Windows10
Hololens2
MixedReality-WebRTC2.0.2
Unity 2019.4.26fc1
Architecture:ARM

Comment: By the way, Above-mentioned transmitting a 331KB picture uses  a Datachannel.

Comment: WebRTC would perform best on fast network (LAN vs. WAN), for your case, I think the Github issue should be the right place to discuss, I saw you already do that: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/issues/774